# Corrupt file when exporting PDF to a directory using ITextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am trying to generate a PDF using ITextSharp, but when I try to open it, it states it's corrupt:

[image: Error Message]

Everything seems to work fine until I open it up.

Code:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 30, 30, 5, 5);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
    document.Open();

     // Style Code 

    #endregion

    document.Close();
    writer.Close();

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer())
    };

    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = filename;
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\mmaslova\Desktop\TEMP\" + filename;
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one error:

```
    Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer())
```

`MemoryStream.GetBuffer()` returns the whole buffer which may be much larger than the actual content. Thus, your `Content` often will contain a PDF with a tail of a lot of garbage bytes. As a PDF processor is expected to read a PDF from its end (where a reference to object cross references can be found), it tries to find that reference at the end of your garbage bytes. This fails, so the file is corrupt. (Actually Adobe Reader and other processors following its lead look for that reference in the last 1024 bytes of the file. This increases the chances of finding it but there still are enough situations in which the reference won't be found.)

You essentially have two choices:

- Either you use `MemoryStream.ToArray()` instead. This method returns only the actual content, not unused trailing bytes. The disadvantage: It creates a copy of those bytes. Depending on the size of your PDFs and your resources, that might mean trouble.
- Or you use `MemoryStream.GetBuffer()` only with methods which also accept a parameter denoting the length of the actual content in that byte array, and set that parameter to `MemoryStream.Length`.

E.g. in your case `ByteArrayContent` also has a constructor

```
public ByteArrayContent (byte[] content, int offset, int count);
```

*([Microsoft docs on `ByteArrayContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.bytearraycontent.-ctor#System_Net_Http_ByteArrayContent__ctor_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_))*

so you can replace

```
    Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer())
```

by

```
    Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.Length)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I needed to move the FileStream before document.Open();

Answer:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 30, 30, 5, 5);
     PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);

     string filePath = @"C:\Users\mmaslova\Desktop\TEMP\" + filename;
     PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
     document.Open(); 

     #endregion

    document.Close();
    writer.Close();

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
    
       Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer())
  
    };

    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = filename;

    return result;

}
```

Comment: In your question you didn't mention that you thought the file of the file stream you didn't write anything into was meant to contain a pdf, in your question it appeared that you meant the http response. The code in your answer still sends broken pdfs to the client.

Comment: @mkl it’s not though? I mentioned it was sending broken PDF’s. i wasn’t sure the exact reason. Turns out it was sending 0 bytes. When I moved the FileStream up, it worked....

Comment: I'm a bit confused, do you eventually serve the file? Or do you serve  the `HttpResponseMessage result`? In the latter case the change you did should not have any effect. In the former case, what is the sense of filling that `HttpResponseMessage result`?

Comment: I am using HttpResponseMessage and then calling it in another function using IHttpActionResult.

Comment: So you don't use that file system file. Thus, your change shouldn't make any difference. Actually you should be able to remove all about the file without that making a difference.

Comment: Got it. This was my first attempt at generating a PDF using ITextSharp. I learned a lot from your comments. I appreciate your help !